# Not able to display attached file through grid view in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to display the uploaded file using command button withing the grid view .My grid view shows all the records and and there is file uploaded for one selected record:

My c# code in asp.net page is :

```
   protected void gvDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    GridViewRow selectedRow = gvDetails.Rows[index];


    if (e.CommandName == "View1")
    {

        LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;

        int fileid = Convert.ToInt32(selectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
        int fileid2 = Convert.ToInt32(selectedRow.Cells[2].Text);

        string name, type;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "select FileName1, FileType1, Emailsent1 from tbSupplierLineItem  Where ShoppingCartNo = @scn AND LineItemNo = @itemno";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@scn", fileid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@itemno", fileid2);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    Response.ContentType = dr["FileType1"].ToString();
                    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + dr["FileName1"] + "\"");
                    Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["Emailsent1"]);
                    Response.End();
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

IN SQLserver 2008 , the table field data type for the attachment is varbinary(MAX)

But when I click the view button in grid view it shows errror like:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

Please help me to fix it

My error is coming in this line `Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["Emailsent1"]);` in my code

Comment: You can't "fix it". The column value was NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (dr.IsDbNull("Emailsent1"))
    return;
```